# How to do betting in C# with roulette (with a betting table)?

Tags: c#

What I have right now is a "Betting Table", a picture box I have placed on my form. What I'm trying to do is make it so that when you click on one of the squares, it prints another image, that of a poker chip, on the respective spot on the board, that part isn't difficult, just time consuming. What I want to know is how I can make this thing read where the images have been placed. If I can, it's an easy task to make it do the math for the betting, again, that is just time consuming. Thank you in advance.

~T-Fox

Answer (score 2):

You'll could create an array in the background that represents the segments on your image.

When a user clicks on a segment on the image, you could update the relevant array[i] with a value to represent a `chip` or number of `chips` assigned to that segment.

You could also use this array for redrawing/repainting your image if you needed to refresh it.

**Edit**

Just to follow up, you'd probably need to create some sort of correlation table between defined areas on your image and the array. Creating a rectangle based on origin and width/height mapped against an array index.

So if a user clicks on a segment in the Image, you can take the cursor X,Y value, compare to see what rectangle it's in, and then update that array value.